# multiple requests shut down mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have some problems with my mysql database.

I configured a server with the database and other services (apache, php) and put run multiple applications.

There are two problems.

1. Every day at the same time mysql fails, and I must go and restart it.
2. Every time I reload the website many times continuously mysql falls, and again and need to restart it.

Mysql logs show:

```
140107 0:09:29 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use$
140107 0:09:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140107 0:09:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140107 0:09:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140107 0:09:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140107 0:09:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
InnoDB: mmap(68681728 bytes) failed; errno 12
140107 0:09:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140107 0:09:29 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140107 0:09:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140107 0:09:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140107 0:09:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140107 0:09:29 [ERROR] Aborting
140107 0:09:29 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

What's wrong with my database?

Comment: I suspect you're running out of virtual memory, see the `mmap failed` error. Anyway, this is a system administration or DBA question, it doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: EC2 micro instance?

Comment: Have you got SWAP space available on your host?

Comment: I do not have SWAP . If I install SWAP solve my problem ?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem of mysql database. The server was running out of memory to solve, I used SWAP.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Barmar is correct.

You do not have enough memory in the server for the InnoDB Buffer Pool.

Since you got the message

```
140107 0:09:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
```

followed by

```
140107 0:09:29 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

you should lower [**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) below 64M in `/etc/my.cnf` and restart mysql.

**SUGGESTION**: If it is withn your budget, you should setup Apache and PHP on a separate server. Connection all webserver requests to the DB thereafter.